# mvn clean install is SUCCESS for my spring-cloud-contract consumer tests, but when I run the tests manually they are FAILING?

Tags: java, maven-surefire-plugin, spring-cloud-contract

I have the spring-cloud-contract tests projects in place where I am doing a consumer-driven contract testing. Instead of going through the code, I just have technical question. I have written my consumer test cases in a separate consumer side application which will talk to the producer stub jar. Everything goes fine, as the test pass if nothing changes in contract and fails when something in contract changes and not updated properly.

But when they fail, when I run the consumer side test cases, they fail manually when I run the test cases as `Run as Tests` in `IDE`. If I do `mvn clean install` builds are passing ? how is this possible ? How will I know if the tests failed ? do i have to run them manually everytime and see ? How will I know if the consumer side tests are failing if I add this code as pipeline build ?

`mvn clean install` is passing even if tests are failing manually when I run them ?

I am not using `skipTests` flag

Comment: I am thinking if you are testing something which involve "relative path " file? `mvn clean install` is running from root folder while in IDE is not.

Comment: Are the tests well isolated from each other? Maybe the tests use eg. static variables, or create files, an in-memory databases, or use any other shared resource? It is actually possible that the result of one test is dependent on the actions from other tests

Comment: Yes, I'm using the maven install feature in Intellij IDE for building the project with test cases. Do you think this has something to do with `maven-failsafe-plugin` ?

Comment: I'm using `surefire-plugin` but still the tests seem to fail

Answer (score 1):

thanks for everyone's suggestion, I have found fix for this. I have not added the naming convention `Test` for my test classes under `src/main/test`, which was causing this issue. Fixed it. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

'mvn clean install' will try to find test-cases in 'src/test/java' only.
Please check once if your test-classes reside at this location.

Comment: Yes, i am using them in the `src/test/java` folder only!